# Attaching events to two items in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a click event that will work when two different items are clicked. 
Is there a way to do this?

For example, normally what I'd do is this:

```
<a id="link1" onclick="doSomething()">link1</a>
<a id="link2" onclick="doSomething()">link2</a>
```

But what I would like to know is whether there is any event overloading of sorts, perhaps like:

```
<script>
$("#link1", "#link2").click(function () { 
 alert('doSomething');

 });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to trigger click only when these two are clicked. i.e. trigger only when both are clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector should look like this:

```
$("#link1, #link2")
```

Take a look at jQuery's [multiple selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$("#link1, #link2").click(function () { 
 alert('doSomething');

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) by comma separating, like this:

```
$('#link1, #link2').click(function () { 
  alert('doSomething');
});
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KdDvm/1/).

---

But an easier approach is usually to give the links a common class, this way whether you have 2 links, no links or 400 links...there's no change to your code.  To do that give them a class like this:

```
<a href="#" class="link">link1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">link2</a>
```

Then use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), like this:

```
$('.link').click(function () { 
  alert('doSomething');
});
```

[You can test that version out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KdDvm/).